# Extension to remove redundent white spaces between lines of code

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

i'm looking for an VS 2010 extension to remove all redundent white spaces between 
and inside scopes of code .

any ideas ?

Comment: Why? Spaces don't take any resources in compiled code and at the same time they make code much more readable. And there will be a difference in perception of what constitutes "redundant" white spaces. I prefer to add 10+ empty lines between private and public class members. It helps me to visualise it.
If you really want to a very simple regex will do it.

Comment: Is (s)he a programmer? If (s)he is not (s)he has nothing at all to do with the source code, if he is and he does not understand importance of spaces in the code then previous note still applies. If he still wants to see the code - display it in HTML page (all spaces will be automatically removed).

Comment: CodeRush extension can do it easily - www.devexpress.com/coderush